# ORA-00932 Trying to overcome the mutate table error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g, ora-00932

I have applied the fallowing instructions about how to overcome the mutate table error:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936

But in my last trigger I got the fallowing error:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger Factura_Detalle_ai
after insert or update of PRODUCTO on Factura_Detalle
begin
                for i in 1 .. state_pkg.newRows.count loop

                        UPDATE Factura_Detalle
                        SET Precio = (SELECT pre.PRECIO
                        FROM PRECIO pre
                        WHERE pre.PRODUCTO = state_pkg.newRows(i));

                end loop;
end;
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13  
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors trigger factura_detalle_ai
Errors for TRIGGER FACTURA_DETALLE_AI:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/23     PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got
         ROWID
```

Any ideas?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Replace your where clause with this:

```
WHERE ROWID = state_pkg.newRows(i));
```

ROWID is a pseudo-column for the address of each row, and it's a data type.

**EDIT:**

Or maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE Factura_Detalle
SET Precio = 
(
    SELECT pre.PRECIO
    FROM PRECIO pre
    WHERE pre.PRODUCTO = Factura_Detalle.PRODUCTO
)
WHERE ROWID = state_pkg.newRows(i);
```

Comment: Hi @jonearles, thanks for your answer, but when I tried to insert a row at the table I got another error:                              ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01410: invalid ROWID
ORA-06512: at "CFD_O.FACTURA_DETALLE_AI", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CFD_O.FACTURA_DETALLE_AI'

Comment: Also I want to compare the foreign key "Producto" from the table "Precio" with the newRows in the where clause in order to retrieve the field "Precio" from the table "Precio"